# pip ssl errors in virtualenv

Tags: python, ssl, pip

Anyone else seen this?  Working with python 2.7.13 on windows.  I'm behind an SSL Intercept and it took me forever to get past the ssl errors on python and pip by installing ceritfi and adding our own cert to the cacert.pem.

BUT this doesn't work in virtualenv, no matter what I try(sames steps) I still get the error -

">pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581) - skipping

Wondering if anyone has seen this and gotten it to work - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org  flask
```

Answer (score 1):

I use middlebox SSL inspection too.

using this: `export PIP_CERT=/etc/ssl/certs/` in your Linux environment works well.

If you did install your CA on the system and run update-ca-certificates